# Can I store the id list of friends of the user of my application?

Tags: save, store, uid, x-facebook-platform

Can I store this data ? I want to save only ID of friends of application user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Per the [Facebook Developer Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) 2.2:

> You may cache data you receive through use of the Facebook API in
>   order to improve your application’s user experience, but you should
>   try to keep the data up to date. This permission does not give you any
>   rights to such data.